# IIS Worker Process NullReferenceException at SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(Int32)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, kentico

A Kentico-9 site for a client of mine has been crashing at seemingly random times.

I've checked the windows server error logs, and found the stack trace of the error.

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(Int32)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(Int32)
   at System.Web.Util.AspCompatApplicationStep.AnyStaObjectsInSessionState(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireSessionOnEnd(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState, System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionOnEndTargetWorkItem.RaiseOnEndCallback()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(System.Web.Util.WorkItemCallback)
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

From there i've setup dumping the application pool process on the exception, hoping that it would lead to some more information about it, but that doesn't seem to contain anything new.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Right now I can only comment on this as there is no clear answer. It seems, that running thread has terminated and it tries to terminate the session, but session is no longer available. Dump would be a good check as you can at least see threads (unless one that was terminated is not there). Also some sort of information regarding what was happening within the application would be good. Lastly, how is the site configured regarding incoming traffic, load balancing and session storage?

Comment: The site gets approximately 7k unique user hits a day.
No load balancing at present, session storage is set to InProc.

In the dump, the thread, call stack and the memory address it's trying to access are there, but it seems like it's only the worker process and not any application code.

Answer (score 0):

*for future Reference:*

we had the exact same issue and fixed it apparenty by changing the session access in our **async handlers** from readonly to rw.

from `IReadOnlySessionState` to `IRequiresSessionState` like this

```cs
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{ 
   ...
}
```

as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecd9f487-7993-4ac9-b953-794abc179569/session-exception-terminates-application-pool?forum=aspstatemanagement) this seems to be also relevant if you are using the `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` attribute in MVC.